# VBA - if replacement = true, change cell color to yellow

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro and I want to record an addon to the below code:

```
Selection.Replace What:="<", replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

New code needed: if the above ended up replacing <, then the cell needs to be marked in yellow (colorindex=6). Which code would allow me to do this?

Comment: `New code needed: Which code would allow me to do this?` What do you think should be done? Where are you stuck? I think you may have misunderstood how stackoverflow operates. You may want to see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please post what you have tried so far. Keep these in mind while posting **1.** What were you expecting? **2.** What is not working? Include Error message if applicable and we will take it from there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replace to replace the format

```
Dim ReplaceRange As Range
Set ReplaceRange = Selection

'define color for ReplaceFormat
With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
    .ColorIndex = 6
End With
'replace the format and text
ReplaceRange.Replace What:="<", replacement:=vbEmpty, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=True, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

Comment: You beat me by 5 sec. Note that you don't need to do it in 2 steps: Just write `Replacement:=vbEmtpy`.

Comment: @FunThomas Nice, I didn't know that `vbEmtpy` works! I fixed it.